# xml-less spring configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm struggling with XML-less setup of a Spring project. Could you suggest some approaches to making this an iterative process? i.e. descirbe the steps of where to obtain configuration, how to find docs, which configs to define first, etc..
My goal is to implement a web app that supports websocket and I already found a very recent stock portfolio example https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio which works great, but when I try to create a simplest webapp that will have a very basic chat, I don't know where to start. I suppose this is all very new and not many are playing with this yet, but if you are, please share, I would be very grateful.

Update: My exact issue is how to dissect WebConfig java of the spring-websocket-portfolio project and rebuild it step by step to achieve a simple chat functionality. I have a spring project going, and it compiles and runs on tomcat 8 successfully(env is fine). the config file in question is this version: [WebConfig.java](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/blob/e2cf08b1605b9a06e56e5dc51ceac3efb95c32eb/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/portfolio/config/WebConfig.java). 
What I am after is what is the best way to create something simple, a starting point, and build on top of it. By the way, the latest WebConfig.java has been much simplified by Rossen, but interestingly it has some compile issues and doesn't work.

Comment: Can you state what are your exact requirements. ? Do you need to know how to setup the environment.? Tools.? Tutorials.? Please specify.

Comment: Just updated my post, have a look, thank you.